# Getting .animate() and .data() to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

There's this strange issue, the second .animate does not work when I use elem.data to get the values, whereas when I use mention the values specifically such as `"left" : "200px"` it seems to work.

I've checked the existence of `elem.data('prevLeft')` and `elem.data('prevTop')` by using `console.log()` just before the code mentioned below and these values exist and are correct.

```
elem.animate({"width":"200px"},3000).animate({
    "left": elem.data('prevLeft'),
    "top": elem.data('prevTop')
 },2000);
```

What seems to be the problem, and is there no way I can pass values stored in a variable to the `.animate()` function?

---

A Stray function was resetting the values, and *that* is why it wasn't working.
I retried all the methods mentioned and all of them worked.

Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jZGSk/ Can you make a jsFiddle of your situation? It seems it must be CSS or some other strange issue. Animate works with `'200' '200px' even 200` it seems

Comment: yep seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/jZGSk/1/

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS your code seems to work in jsfiddle, it doesn't work in when I integrate it with the rest of my code though.

I'm doing a elem.data("prevLeft",elem.css('left')) to store the value though, But I don't know how that would/should affect anything.

And I don't have any specific css added just top,left,position and an id and a class (Which don't have a corresponding stylesheet btw, using them just for js/jQuery) added inline.

Comment: Well if I did `elem.css('left')` in my code, it would retrieve `0px`, which it is already at, so obviously it won't move anywhere!

Comment: Not if the left was explicitly set in the style attribute.

But I found the error. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Make sure you post your answer in the question or something, incase someone else has the similar issue!

Comment: I added the problem to the end of the answer, if the explanation is not elaborate enough, I will be happy to elaborate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT, try this:

```
var prevLeft = elem.data('prevLeft'),
var prevTop = elem.data('prevTop');

elem.animate({'width':'200px'},3000).animate({'top':prevTop,'left':prevLeft},2000);
```

Though if svenhesse's answer didn't work, I'm not sure this will.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. It's the same problem, only the width animation works. :-S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var conf = {
    left: elem.data('left'), 
    right: elem.data('right')
};

elem.animate(conf, 200);
```